# Error indexing text from Apache Tika in Solr

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, solr, apache-tika

I am trying to integrate [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) with Solr so that text extracted by Tika could be indexed in Solr.
I tried the following code:

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;

import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;

import org.apache.tika.metadata.DublinCore;

import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;

import org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypes;

import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;

import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;

import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;

import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;

import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class Main {

    private static SolrServer solr;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {

        try {

            solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/#/"); 



            String path = "C:\\content\\";

            String file_html = path + "mobydick.htm";

            String file_txt = path + "/home/ben/abc.warc";

            String file_pdf = path + "callofthewild.pdf";

            processDocument(file_html);

            processDocument(file_txt);

            processDocument(file_pdf);

            solr.commit();

        }

        catch  (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }           
    }



    private static void processDocument(String pathfilename)  {

        try {

            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(pathfilename));

            //use Apache Tika to convert documents in different formats to plain text

            ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler(10*1024*1024);

            Metadata meta = new Metadata();

            Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser(); //handles documents in different formats:

            ParseContext context = new ParseContext();   

            parser.parse(input, textHandler, meta, context); //convert to plain text

            //collect metadata and content from Tika and other sources

            //document id must be unique, use guide

        UUID guid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();

        String docid = guid.toString();

            //Dublin Core metadata (partial set)

            String doctitle = meta.get(DublinCore.TITLE);

            String doccreator = meta.get(DublinCore.CREATOR); 

            //other metadata

            String docurl = pathfilename; //document url

            //content

            String doccontent = textHandler.toString();

            //call to index

            indexDocument(docid, doctitle, doccreator, docurl, doccontent);

        }
        catch  (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
    }   



    private static void indexDocument(String docid, String doctitle, String 

doccreator, String docurl, String doccontent)  {

        try {

            SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();

            doc.addField("id", docid);

            //map metadata fields to default schema
            //location: path\solr-4.7.2\example\solr\collection1\conf\schema.xml

            //Dublin Core
            //thought: schema could be modified to use Dublin Core

            doc.addField("title", doctitle);

            doc.addField("author", doccreator);

            //other metadata

            doc.addField("url", docurl);

            //content (and text)
            //per schema, the content field is not indexed by default, used for returning and highlighting document content
            //the schema "copyField" command automatically copies this to the "text" field which is indexed

            doc.addField("content", doccontent);

            //indexing
            //when a field is indexed, like "text", Solr will handle tokenization, stemming, removal of stopwords etc, per the schema defn

            //add to index

            solr.add(doc);  

        } 

        catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

}   

  } 

}
```

Unfortunately I am hitting the **Error** below:

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**
>   **org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException     at Main.main(Main.java:28)**
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 1 more

Could you please help me with the resolution of this issue?

Comment: Did you add all the required dependency jars to your classpath?

Comment: Yes i add all the required dependency jars in classpath ,also this httpResponse but showing same error